# Passing stored values into google maps for multiple markers Node/Mongo/Express/EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to pass values from mongodb into the google maps script for multiple markers. The map loads but I can not find a way to define my customer to then loop through the locations. I found a few answers here but being that my experience level is a beginner I'm finding things a bit vague. Here is my route

```
router.get("/", function(req, res){
// Get all customers from DB
Customer.find({}, function(err, customers){

    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render("customers/index", {customers: customers});

        console.log(customers)
    }
});
```

Here is the Google Maps Script

```
<script>

function initialize() {
    var mapProp = {

        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.9526, -75.1652),
        zoom:8,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map =new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapProp);
    var customers = [{customers: customers}];
    customers.forEach(function (customer) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(Number(customer.latitude), Number(customer.longitude)),
            map: map,
            title: "test"
        });
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have tried moving things around but keep getting the following error
Uncaught ReferenceError: customers is not defined at customers:28

How do I properly define the customer? 
Any help on this issue would be awesome. 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

if  customer  is  an  array   which  should  be .   are  you  sure   the  customer  contains  the  array  ???

Answer (score 0):

i  dont  know  what  your dataset and  al look likes   but  1st  you should check  its  an  array then    do  this

```
  var newAArray= []
  JSON.stringify(customers).foreach(customer){
   newAArray.push({location: newgoogle.maps.LatLng(customer.lat),customer.lon()
   }
```

Comment: thanks, but customers are still undefined. I am returning an Object I believe {customers: customers}....this is from the console.log(customers) in my route.   { _id: 58a1c5b10ca3e7229a52e79e,
    lng: -75.15944499999999,
    lat: 39.95261600000001,
    address: '1150 Filbert St.',
    city: 'Philadelphia',
    state: 'Pennsylvania',
    zip: '19107',
    }, Maybe I have your suggestion in the wrong place? Where should I put your code? Sorry for needing some hand holding here!